# Is it possible view entire logcat of Android device (i.e. not attached to a specific process)?

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, adb, logcat

Simple question, but is it possible to view the entire logcat output of an Android device in Android Studio? Meaning all of the logs from everything that's happening on the device, not necessarily only those generated by the app in development.

I ask because I have a bug that does not show up on the debug build (i.e. I build it in Android studio and run it on a device), but it DOES show up in the production build for the same code, and I would love to see what is happening on the device.

Essentially, I'm asking if it's possible to select nothing from the following dropdown menu.[image: Image of logcat with dropdown of processes next to the dropdown of devices]

Comment: To the right of what you have in the screenshot, there is an additional drop-down. Choose "No Filters" there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `no filters` option in your Android studio Logcat.
[image]

How you can select nothing in processes spinner:

- Stop your application
- Close the emulator
- Press launch in android studio
- Cancel launching the application
- Emulator is still launching
- You have `no debuggable processes` in your spinner.